# What are the storage classes in D?

Tags: d

Up until now I was under the impression that things like `immutable` and `const` were storage classes.  In a recent [video (at around 11:55)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2012/The-D-Programming-Language) Walter Bright states that `immutable` is not a storage class, but rather it's a type constructor.  In the [official documentation](http://dlang.org/declaration.html), `immutable`, `const`, and among many other keywords, are listed as being storage classes:

```
StorageClass:
abstract
auto
const
deprecated
enum
extern
final
immutable
inout
shared
nothrow
override
pure
__gshared
Property
scope
static
synchronized
```

Is this list wrong? Some of it doesn't make sense(e.g., deprecated, override).

I know `static` and `ref` are storage classes, but what's the rest?  And which one of the keywords in D are type constructors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would point out that there is a big difference between a grammar rule named *StorageClass*, and what is semantically a storage class in the language. The grammar rules have to do with parsing, not the semantic phase of compilation.

First off, [TDPL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361), chapter 8, is explicitly about type qualifiers (for which Walter used the term type constructor). There are only 3 of them in D:

> const
>     immutable
>     shared

All three of them are a part of the type that they modify. Such is not true with storage classes such as `ref`.

`inout` is what TDPL calls a "wildcard qualifier symbol," so it's a placeholder for a type qualifier rather than really being either a type qualifer or a storage class.

Now, as to what's a storage classes or not, I give two quotes from TDPL:

> Each function parameter (`base` and `exponent` in the example above) has, in addition to its type, an optional *storage class* that decides the way that arguments are passed to the function when invoked.

(from pages 6 - 7)

> Although `static` is not related to passing arguments to functions, discussing it here is appropriate because, just like `ref`, `static` applied to data is a *storage class*, meaning an indication about a detail regarding how data is stored.

(from page 137)

Also, there's this line with regards to storage classes in C which seems to be [used](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/CONCEPT/storage_class.html) [quite a bit](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_storage_classes.htm) in explanations on storage classes in C found online:

> A storage class defines the scope (visibility) and life time of variables and/or functions within a C Program.

A storage class has no effect on the type of a variable, just how it's stored. Unfortunately, I can't find an exact list of storage classes in D, and people are quite liberal with the term storage class, using it even when it doesn't apply. Pretty much *any* attribute applied to a type save for access modifiers seems to get called a storage class, depending on who's talking. However, there are a few which are beyond a doubt storage classes:

> enum (when used as a manifest constant)
>     extern
>     lazy
>     out
>     ref
>     scope
>     static

`lazy`, `out`, and `ref` can be used to modify function parameters and indicate how they're passed, whereas `enum` and `static` are used to indicate how the variables are stored (which is nowhere in the case of `enum`, since manifest constants are copy-pasted everywhere that they're used rather than being actual variables). `extern` affects linkage.

`in` is a hybrid, since it's a synonym for `scope const`, and while `scope` is a storage class, `const` is a type qualifier.

The online documentation also refers to `auto` and `synchronized` as storage classes, though I don't know on what basis. `auto` is like `inout` in that it's a placeholder (in its case a placeholder for a type rather than a type qualifier) and therefore indicates nothing about how a type is stored, so I wouldn't have thought that it would be a storage class. `synchronized` doesn't modify variables but rather classes.

`__gshared` is probably a storage class as well, though it's a bit funny, since it does more or less what `shared` (which is a type qualifier) does, but it's not part of the type.

Beyond that, I don't know. The fact that `synchronized` is listed as a storage class implies that some of the others (such as `final`) might be, but (like `synchronized`) they have nothing to do with how variables are stored or linked. So, I don't know how they could be considered storage classes.

I'll ask on the newsgroup though and see if I can get a more definitive list.

**EDIT**: It seems that there is no definitive, official list of storage classes in D. The term is used for almost any attribute used on a variable declaration which doesn't affect its type (i.e. not a type qualifier). It seems that Walter and Andrei tend to make a big point about the type qualifiers to underline which attributes actually affect the type of a variable, but the term storage class hasn't been given anywhere near the same level of importance and ends up being used informally rather than per any rigorous definition.

Comment: auto is not a placeholder for a type. It's just a no-op starage class which is put in front of declarations without any other sc or type so the compiler recognizes it as declaration and infers the type. immutable x = 5; works just fine without auto.

Comment: @Mafi, *actually*, `auto` can be thought of as the storage class for stack variables, as it is in C and C++. The `auto` keyword originates from this usage and its semantics were *expanded* to allow for type inference of variables with no other storage classes; it was only at this point that the keyword became usable outside of local variables. However, the `auto` keyword was a rare sight before its type inference semantics, and is still a rare sight in C, as `auto` is the default storage class for local variables. It's called "auto" because it means "automatic lifetime", i.e. a stack variable.